# How to rectify the error GPR_UNREACHABLE_COD in grpc in xcode9

Tags: ios, objective-c, grpc

I'm using the grpc in my ios app.
after updating it to xcode 9.0 when i try to build the app it's throwing the error as

```
/Users/xxxxx/iosApp/Pods/gRPC-Core/src/core/lib/surface/channel_stack_type.c:39:1: Control may reach end of non-void function

/Users/xxxxx/iosApp/Pods/gRPC-Core/src/core/lib/surface/channel_stack_type.c:57:1: Control may reach end of non-void function
```

Is there any ways to solve it??.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

grpc made the fix on the version 1.6.5